# Python: converting a nested list into a simple list with coord positions

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I am learning python and panda3d currently.
I have a nested list which i need to convert into a list of coordinates.

my input is

```
    [['g,g', 'g,g'], ['d,d', 'd,d,d', 'd,d], ['s,s', 's,s']]
```

The Output that I need is another list:

```
    [(0,0,0,'s'),(0,1,0,'s'),(1,0,0,'s'),(1,1,0,'s'),(0,0,1,'d'),(0,1,1,'d'),(1,0,1,'d'),(1,1,1,'d'),(1,2,1,'d'),(2,0,1,'d'),(2,1,1,'d'),(0,0,2,'g'),(0,1,2,'g'),(1,0,2,'g'),(1,1,2,'g')]
```

this simple list conversion is scrambling my brain. o.0

EDIT: more info:
in the input list, the last nested list represents the base layer.

The idea was to convert string i have written in a file into coordinate points. This is the content of the file:

```
    [LVL02]
    g,g
    g,g
    [/LVL02]
    [LVL01]
    d,d
    d,d,d
    d,d
    [/LVL01]
    [LVL00]
    s,s
    s,s
    [/LVL00]
```

this should give me a very basic map maker. each level is a flat 2d surface.

```
    [LVL02]
    g,g             (0,0,2,'g'),(0,1,2,'g')
    g,g             (1,0,2,'g'),(1,1,2,'g')
    [/LVL02]
    [LVL01]
    d,d             (0,0,1,'d'),(0,1,1,'d')
    d,d,d           (1,0,1,'d'),(1,1,1,'d'),(1,2,1,'d')
    d,d             (2,0,1,'d'),(2,1,1,'d')
    [/LVL01]
    [LVL00]
    s,s             (0,0,0,'s'), 0,1,0,'s')
    s,s             (1,0,0,'s'),(1,1,0,'s')
    [/LVL00]
```

ie. (xaxis,yaxis,zaxis, type)

Comment: What is the rule for how your input list is transformed to the output list?  How do you know what coordinates get mapped to which letters?

Comment: What brc said. If you cannot state the rule then at least make the letters unique - in this example it is unclear which input `'d'` maps to which output `'d'`

Comment: updated the info. Hopefully it is clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *might* be this:

```
l = [['g,g', 'g,g'], ['d,d', 'd,d,d', 'd,d'], ['s,s', 's,s']]
output = [ (x, y, z, v) for z, l1 in enumerate(l[::-1]) for y, l2 in enumerate(l1) for x, v in enumerate(l2.split(',')) ]
```

... but as it has been written, it is not clear what the rule is exactly. In nested loops:

```
output = []
for z,l1 in enumerate(l[::-1]):
    for y, l2 in enumerate(l1):
        for x, v in enumerate(l2.split(',')):
            output.append((x, y, z, v))
```

Comment: my apologies. am currently running on my 4th cup of coffee. :/
updated the info.

Comment: looks good. I'll check it with some more. I never can wrap my head around how you put up multiple for loops in the same line in python. :(

Comment: I have another request. Can you write the same code in nested loops? I am unable to grasp the logic in here.